Button shows sometimes and sometimes not
I'm trying to track watch time of a video with using JavaScript. But the problem is sometimes the script works well and sometimes it doesn't. I want to show a "Next video" button when the video is 90% watched by user, in ideal scenario the button shows up button sometimes it just doesn't, How can I fix this issue?
This is my HTML, I'm using Bootstrap CDN along with HTML:


<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="cursor-pointer pt-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
   <video class="w-50" poster="" id="plyr-video-player" playsinline controls>
      <source src="https://therapywebsite.s3.amazonaws.com/Binaural+Beats+Fast+5+min+meditation+Stress+Relief+%5Bxc3MacYfdbI%5D.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   </video>
</div>
<div class="pt-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
   <h5>Welcome to this session</h5>
   <button class=" d-none w-25 btn btn-primary me-3" id="next-video-btn">Next video</button>
</div>

<!-- & this is my script: -->
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
      const video = document.getElementById("plyr-video-player");
      const nextVideoBtn = document.getElementById("next-video-btn");

      const videoId = 1;
      const postInterval = 10;

      let playedCount = 0;
      let lastPlayedTime = 0;
      let totalWatchedTime = 0;
      let actualWatchedTime = 0;
      let isTabActive = true;
      let skipDetected = false;
      let isVideoVisible = true;

      document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
        isTabActive = !document.hidden;
      });

      const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          isVideoVisible = entry.isIntersecting;
        });
      }, {threshold: 0.5});
      observer.observe(video);

      video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
        const videoDuration = Math.floor(video.duration);
        const playedCountThreshold = Math.floor(videoDuration * 0.9);

        if (videoDuration){
          console.log("Metadata loaded")
        } else{
          console.log("Metadata isn't loaded yet!!")
        }

        const showVideoBtn = () =>{
          if (video.currentTime > playedCountThreshold) {
            if (nextVideoBtn.classList.contains("d-none")) {
              nextVideoBtn.classList.remove("d-none");
            }
          }
        };

        function autoPlay() {
          return video.play();
        }
        autoPlay().catch(error => {
          console.error("Autoplay failed:", error);
        });
        setTimeout(autoPlay, 1000)

        function trackVideo(eventType, currentTime){
          currentTime = Math.floor(currentTime);
          if (isTabActive && isVideoVisible){
            if (currentTime > playedCountThreshold && lastPlayedTime <= playedCountThreshold) {
              playedCount++;
            }
            if (eventType !== "play" || eventType === "timeupdate"){
              const timeDiff = Math.max(0, currentTime - lastPlayedTime);
              actualWatchedTime += timeDiff;
            } else if (eventType === "seeked") {
              skipDetected = true;
              const skippedTime = Math.max(0, currentTime - lastPlayedTime);
              actualWatchedTime -= skippedTime;
            }
            totalWatchedTime = actualWatchedTime;

            fetch("/track_video/", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                video_id: videoId,
                played_count: playedCount,
                video_duration: videoDuration,
                last_played_time: lastPlayedTime,
                total_watched_time: totalWatchedTime,
              })
            });
          }
          lastPlayedTime = currentTime;
        }

        video.addEventListener("play", () => trackVideo('play', video.currentTime));
        video.addEventListener("pause", () => trackVideo("pause", video.currentTime));
        video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
          if (video.currentTime - lastPlayedTime >= postInterval) {
            trackVideo('timeupdate', video.currentTime);
          }
          showVideoBtn();
        });
        video.addEventListener("seeked", () =>{
          skipDetected = true;
          lastPlayedTime = Math.floor(video.currentTime)
          trackVideo("seeked", video.currentTime)
        });
      });
      nextVideoBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        window.location.href = "/next_video.html";
      });
    });
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>




I tried your code and it worked fine on chrome. Is there any error or log when it doesn't work? also, which browser have you tried?

I tried, Google chorme, Firefox & Brave all I got same results from each browser.
I got some error is this:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request.

Improve this function showVideoBtn by adding d-block when you are removing d-none. Update the condition, I hope it will work.

I receive an error because the code attempts to play a video without my permission. Very spam-like behavior. You should probably not do that.

@Heretic Monkey, Its client's requirement to autoplay the video, I'd never promote this kind of spam like behavior!!

"name": "NotAllowedError",
"message": "play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." <- expected result if trying to autoplay a non-muted video

fixed it by using the load method.
